# Unexpected token ':"Condeco"' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, hashtable, azure-powershell

I have one DevOps release pipeline. When I update my app service it automatically deletes any app configuration added previously by the user. So I want to get all the app settings and store them into variable then after the app service update again add them back to the app setting.

**To store app setting into variable**

```
$webApp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $(Parameter.ResourceGroupName) -Name $(Parameters.AppName)  
$appSetting = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$hash = @{}
foreach($kvp in $appSetting) {
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}
Write-Host ($hash | Out-String)
$jsonObject = [PSCustomObject]$hash
$convertJson = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 100 -Compress
Write-Host "JSON : " $convertJson
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storeAppSetting;]$convertJson"
```

**Print JSON value**

```
{"issuer":"Condeco","EnterpriseRedisAccess":"true","RedisConnectionString":"Redis","d":"d","APIBaseURL":"https://abc.azurewebsites.net","secret":"XXXXX=","NotificationPusher":"https://abc.xyz.com/NotificationPusher","audience":"XXXXX","SwaggerTitle":"Condeco","EnterpriseURL":"https://abc.xyz.com/"}
```

**Now I want to use that variable to set the app setting again**

```
Write-Host "Get Variable : " $(storeAppSetting)
```

**Error**

```
2022-04-26T09:03:29.7642657Z ##[error]At D:\a\_temp\302fc4cc-24ff-4ad1-b04e-f4b1331dc00f.ps1:2 char:35
+ Write-Host "Get Json : " {"issuer":"Condeco","EnterpriseRedisAccess": ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ':"Condeco"' in expression or statement.

At D:\a\_temp\302fc4cc-24ff-4ad1-b04e-f4b1331dc00f.ps1:2 char:45
+ Write-Host "Get Json : " {"issuer":"Condeco","EnterpriseRedisAccess": ...
+                                             ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
```

Comment: Not clear what you're exactly trying to do but in this line: `Write-Host "Get Variable : " $(storeAppSetting)` you're missing a `$` sign in the variable name. Should be `Write-Host "Get Variable :  $($storeAppSetting)"`

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same command as you are using and getting the invalid `cmdlt` error as shown below.

[image]

And as suggested by @*Remko*, We have tried to use the same and not getting any errors.

"***Instead of using `Write-Host "Get Variable : " $(storeAppSetting)` try to use this:- `Write-Host "Get Variable :  $($storeAppSetting)"`*** "

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [**DC|Azure app settings task in Azure pipeline throws invalid JSON error when supplying with variable with powershell**](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-app-settings-task-in-Azure-pipelin/1652695?space=21&entry=problem)
- [***BLOG|Update application settings for Azure App Service using PowerShell***](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/02/26/apply-update-application-settings-for-azure-app-service-using-powershell/)